# How to find the current element index which is dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have coded some simple function which allow me to add order. I have also dynamically created the button which when called will remove the current html element which is a table row. Now, I am stuck with finding the current element index which I needed so I can use splice to remove it from the array.

```js
const order = [];

const customer = {
  name: '',
  totalCups: 0
}

$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
  debugger

  var itemName = $('#customerName');
  var itemTotalCups = $('#customerTotalCups');

  customer.name = itemName.val();
  customer.totalCups = itemTotalCups.val();

  // Data structure Queue
  order.push(Object.assign({}, customer));

  // UI - HTML rendering - start
  if (order.length === 1) {
    // Create table column name
    $('#AllOrders').append('<table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered"><tr><td>Customer</td><td>Cups</td><td></td></tr></table>');

  }

  var itemElement = `<tr><td>${itemName.val()}</td><td>${itemTotalCups.val()}</td><td><a class='del' href='#'>Cancel order</a></td></tr>`;

  $('#tbl').append(itemElement);
  // UI - HTML rendering - end

  $('.del').click(function(e) {

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    // Delete order object
    debugger
    //var elm = $(this).parent().text().substr(0, $(this).parent().text().length-1);
    console.log(elm);
    console.log(order.indexOf(elm));

    //order.splice(order.indexOf(elm),1);
    //order.splice(2,1);

    // Delete HTML element
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  })

  // Reset textbox
  itemName.val("");
  itemTotalCups.val("");

  // Optional Design
  $('#ViewAllOrders').click();
  debugger;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="customerName" type="text" />
<input id="customerTotalCups" type="number" />
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
<div id="AllOrders"></div>
```

I search for the solution but can't figure out the commented code below to find the element

```
 //var elm = $(this).parent().text().substr(0, $(this).parent().text().length-1);
```

I am stuck inside `$('.del').click` event handler.

Comment: Your code does not produce a table.

Comment: ok, sorry. let me check to see what I have missed out

Comment: Found it. It is because I have hidden the output at start. It is okay now. The code works. Just that the delete function is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the element in the `order` array by getting the index of the row where the clicked cancel button is.

To do so, you have to first get the current row. You can use the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
```

Now, you can get the index of the current row through the [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index) method. You have to take into account that you have the `tr` for the header, you we need to substract one:

```
var index = $row.index() - 1;
```

Your final code should look like:

```
$('.del').click(function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var index = $row.index() - 1;
    order.splice(index, 1);

    // Delete HTML element
    $row.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the parent `tr` element and use that element to find the customer name and delete that node from DOM.

Couple of methods you want to try out:

> 1. `.closest()`: find the first match in the parent DOM hierarchy 
>      https://api.jquery.com/closest
> 2. `.filter()`: filter an array based on some condition
>      https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

So, basically you can find the closest `tr` node using `closest` and then find the customer name from within this `tr`'s first `td` element.
Then, use `filter` on order to remove its instance from the `order` array.
Below is the changed code from the snippet:

```
 $('.del').click(function(e) {

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    // Delete order object
    var elm = $(this).closest('tr');
    var nameToDelete = elm.find('td:first').text();

    // filter out order
    order = order.filter(item => item.name !== nameToDelete);
    console.log('order now is = ', order);
    // Delete HTML element
    elm.remove();
  });
```

More appropriately, learn about using **HTML data-* Attributes** along with `id` and `class` that could really ease up DOM manipulation. There are many samples online. Give that a try.
Cheers!

```js
var order = [];

const customer = {
  name: '',
  totalCups: 0
};

$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
  var itemName = $('#customerName');
  var itemTotalCups = $('#customerTotalCups');

  customer.name = itemName.val();
  customer.totalCups = itemTotalCups.val();

  // Data structure Queue
  order.push(Object.assign({}, customer));

  // UI - HTML rendering - start
  if (order.length === 1) {
    // Create table column name
    $('#AllOrders').append('<table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered"><tr><td>Customer</td><td>Cups</td><td></td></tr></table>');

  }

  var itemElement = `<tr><td>${itemName.val()}</td><td>${itemTotalCups.val()}</td><td><a class='del' href='#'>Cancel order</a></td></tr>`;

  $('#tbl').append(itemElement);
  // UI - HTML rendering - end

  $('.del').click(function(e) {

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    // Delete order object
    var elm = $(this).closest('tr');
    var nameToDelete = elm.find('td:first').text();

    // filter out order
    order = order.filter(item => item.name !== nameToDelete);
    console.log('order now is = ', order);
    // Delete HTML element
    elm.remove();
  });

  // Reset textbox
  itemName.val("");
  itemTotalCups.val("");

  // Optional Design
  $('#ViewAllOrders').click();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="customerName" type="text" />
<input id="customerTotalCups" type="number" />
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
<div id="AllOrders"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks . I will try out your solution.

Comment: I did mention it another way around, by using `filter` method, it can be removed without index.

Comment: Anyhow, if the `index` is itself mandatory, it should be ideally added in data- attributes, something like `<tr data-index="0">...</tr>` when appending it in the DOM on `btnAdd` click

Comment: oic. Thanks for sharing. Appreciate it a lot.